# Trying to run a headless pi remotely from a Windows 10 or Android tablet using VNC, but VNC slows unacceptably when it's monitor is unplugged

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

RealVNC viewer on Android tablet and Windows 10 pro PC.
RealVNC server on raspberry pi 4 8gb running ubuntu 20.0.4 with XCFE desktop.
When viewing/running the pi from any platform with a monitor attached to pi, it operates normally.  It's quite snappy.
If you disconnect the monitor from the pi, it slows to unacceptable speeds, e.g. type a letter, 2 seconds later it appears.
Same behavior on wired or wireless.  All home/local networks
Application is to run a telescope setup remotely and unattended using KStars/Ekos.
XRDP/Microsoft RD does work well but I prefer the VNC.
Also, this behavior did not occur when running raspian.
Also, typing appearance speed is normal when entering your credentials at the login screen then resumes the slow pace when it finishes loading the desktop.
Will try a fresh install of ubuntu and the KDE plasma DE.  UPDATE:  KDE plasma had no change of behavior

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience running plain vanilla Ubuntu 20.04 on a Pi4 and was able to overcome it by using a HDMI dummy in place of the monitor.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I have been down several rabbit holes since posting and  fixed it by switching to raspian which comes with a VNC server.  Weird science.

Comment: Yes, that works.  But if you prefer to stay with Ubuntu, for whatever benefits a 64 bit system brings you, then the dummy is the only way I've found so far.  Good luck  with your project.